# Poetry cannot handle sources which redirect after setting cert

Tags: python, ssl, python-poetry, http-status-code-303, pypiserver

I have a pypi server, TLS server cert signed by self signed CA.

I added it as a source (default, secondary = false) to my `toml` file using

`poetry source add mypypiserver https://server.url/`

I added the CA cert using

`poetry config certificates.mypypiserver.cert /path/to/ca.crt`

When attempting to add external packages from pypi, such as `matplotlib`, even if I specify the source as pypi, I get an `SSLError`.

`poetry add --source pypi matplotlib`

Verbose logging tells me it tries to access `/python-dateutil/` which results in a `303` redirect to `https://pypi.org/simple/python-dateutil/`.

Errors:

`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)`

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/python-dateutil/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))`

I suspect this is because the certificate of `pypi.org` does not match the self signed CA certificate.

How can this be resolved?